a theoretical approach to injecting custom keystrokes to a computer through electromagnetic signal injecion
Is it feasible for an attacker to use a malicious electromagnetic signal to remotely inject arbitrary data into USB data lines, specifically the D+ and D- lines, as if using them as antennas? I am interested in understanding whether the data lines could inadvertently act as receivers under certain conditions, potentially allowing for something that is similar to a Bluetooth keyboard attack.


potentially allowing for something that is similar to a Bluetooth keyboard attack.

What you describe wouldn't even remotely resemble a bluetooth attack. The common thing between both would be "involves one or more computers".

Is it feasible for an attacker to use a malicious electromagnetic signal to remotely inject arbitrary data into USB data lines, specifically the D+ and D- lines, as if using them as antennas?

No. In the USB cable, these are intentionally close together, so that any interference would be on both lines, and they are (pseudo) differential lines, so such interference wouldn't matter.

Is it theoretically possible? Yes, given infinite resources and time. Is it remotely feasible? No, absolutely not. Any equipment capable of doing this would be large to the point that it'd be extremely obvious the attack is happening.
There are much easier ways to inject keystrokes into a computer.

USB uses differential signaling which greatly reduces the amount of signal picked up by the wires as antennas. A Bluetooth attack uses an existing interface that is specifically designed to receive wireless signals. Is it technically possible? Maybe for an attacker with nation state capabilities.
